# Parsing XML data objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, cookies

I am trying to parse XML data. I did not use XMLParser. I used this below code and somehow it worked. I parsed XML as JSON and I was getting response in dictionary format. Below is my code -

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

     [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

       NSError *jsonError;

     if (error == nil){

     NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

     if (jsonError) {

     NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);

     failureBlock(@{@"ErrorCode": [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)jsonError.code],

     @"ErrorText": jsonError.localizedDescription});

     } else {

     NSLog(@"success : %@",jsonResponse);

     successBlock(jsonResponse);

     }

     }else{

     failureBlock(@{@"ErrorCode": [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)error.code],

     @"ErrorText": error.localizedDescription});

     }

     }] resume];
```

Though this was working but all of a sudden I started getting error message like -

```
ErrorCode = 3840;
    ErrorText = "The data couldn\U2019t be read because it isn\U2019t in the correct format.";
```

Then how it was working earlier? Can someone please guide me, how I can use correct XML Parsing. Also the xml url if first redirecting to a login page which is being bypassed in the above code and we get the XML response directly. In the app we have a UIWebView container for login and we get cookies. Those cookies are applied on every service call. In above code, when it was working, it was bypassing the login page and returning the response in json format. I also tried this below code -

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

     [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

         NSXMLParser *xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

         [xmlparser setDelegate:self];

         [xmlparser parse];


     }] resume];
```

And then wrote didStartElement, foundCharacters and didEndElement. But it is trying to parse the login page itself. Login page is not bypassed if I use NSXMLParser.

Please help, any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Convert your response to a string format `NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
`, NSLog the resulting string and check whether it is in the correct format.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ for JSON or http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ for XML to validate whether the response is correct.

Comment: @Harsh Yes i did print the data and it seems like my first approach was not bypassing the login page again. I changed the URL and it started working but Is first approach was right to parse XML?

Comment: XML and JSON are two totally different data-interchange formats. The first part mentioned in your question only parses JSON formats and 2nd part mentioned by you only parses XML data.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this link form XML parsing: https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

And Also try this code :

```
NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your string"];


NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        failure(error);
    } else if(response)
    {
        NSDictionary * jsonDic =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLData:data];
        NSLog(@"Response print Hear%@",jsonDic);

    }
}];
```